# how to replace duplicated subquery?

Tags: postgresql

I got a query

```
SELECT  name AS name, 
        count(group_name) AS all_test_cases,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM test_cases AS tc2 WHERE tc2.group_name = tg.name AND status = 'OK'  ) AS passed_test_cases,
        tg.test_value * (SELECT count(*) FROM test_cases AS tc2 WHERE tc2.group_name = name AND status = 'OK') AS total_value
  FROM test_groups AS tg 
  LEFT JOIN test_cases AS tc
     ON tg.name = tc.group_name
  GROUP BY name, test_value      
  ORDER BY total_value DESC, name ASC
```

How I can replace duplicated subquery:

```
tg.test_value * (SELECT count(*) FROM test_cases AS tc2 WHERE tc2.group_name = name AND status = 'OK') AS total_value
```

with something more efficient in postgres without stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
with cte_test_cases as (
  SELECT group_name, 
         count(*) filter (where status = 'OK') as passed_test_cases,
         count(*) as all_test_cases
    FROM test_cases  
   GROUP BY group_name
)
SELECT tg.name, 
       tc.all_test_cases,
       tc.passed_test_cases,
       tg.test_value * tc.passed_test_cases AS total_value
  FROM test_groups AS tg 
  LEFT JOIN cte_test_cases AS tc
         ON tg.name = tc.group_name
  ORDER BY total_value DESC, name ASC
```